# Need a game with AI techqniques

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, python

I want to learn Artificial Intelligence techniques by writing a game (or maybe any fun project). Can you suggest any games? Consider that I'm a beginner in AI, but have basic knowledge Algorithms and Data structures (graph algorithms and stuff like that). I'm going to use Python.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your teachers, if any.